# Create a excel formula that combines 2 tables

Tags: excel-formula

I have 2 tables. Table 1 has employees and Table 2 has codes and their values.

For each employee row in Table 1 by looking up the last 5 characters and matching it Table 2 Column header,I want to insert new rows with all of the Table 2 Code rows and correspondnig "Plan" column value.

For Example, in Table1 1st row EE_Plan1, the last 5 characters "Plan1" should match the 2nd column in Table2, get the plan values (123,879) and insert new code rows as shown below in END RESULT.

Really appreciate any help with creating a formula. Thank you!!

```
                TABLE1

                Employee
                --------
                EE_Plan1
                EE_Plan2
                EE_Plan3


                TABLE2

                Code        Plan1       Plan2       Plan3
                ----        -----       -----       -----   
                DND         123         456         jgh         
                ABC         879         978         ajs     



                END RESULT

                Employee    Code        Plan Desc
                --------    ----        ---------
                EE_Plan1    DND         123
                EE_Plan1    ABC         879

                EE_Plan2    DND         456
                EE_Plan2    ABC         978

                EE_Plan3    DND         jgh
                EE_Plan3    ABC         ajs
```

Answer (score 0):

Vlookups are your friend here. Use a VLOOKUP to locate the corresponding value on the other table and place a cell's value in a different table by reference of Employee. Sorting the sheet before a lookup can help tremendously and set Range Looup to False.

```
    =VLOOKUP(lookup_value,table_array,col_index_num,range_lookup)
```

For returning multiple values see [this article from Microsoft](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/how-to-look-up-a-value-in-a-list-and-return-multiple-corresponding-values-HA001226038.aspx).

Comment: Thanks ShellNinja. I'll give it a try.